# read in csv file and 2007.1 (2007 Jan) changed to 2007.10 (2007 Oct) and as.data does not work

Tags: r

The first pic what it looks like on csv file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzAbb.png)

The second pic is what it reads in R:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbXCq.png)

The first date is changed from "2007.1" to "2007.10". If the month is January it will be changed to October when I read in the csv file. I am trying to make this variable into a data frame. Can someone help?

Then my code looks like this:

```
df <- read.csv("PS_09_orangutans.csv")
n.time <- paste(df$date, ".01", sep = '')         # add day 
n.time
n.time <- as.Date(n.time)            # make Date class
```

The error is: Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: Are you sure? Are you saying that 2007.10 is Jan '07 and 2008.01 is Jan '08? From the sequencing it looks like 2007.10 is actually Oct '07.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what code you are using to load the CSV. Your issue should probably be fixed there, by specifying you want `date` to be read as character data instead of as numeric. That way you can control how the dates are parsed explicitly.

Comment: this is my read csv. df <- read.csv("PS_09_orangutans.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",") Do you know how to specify to read date as character instead of as numeric?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `anydate()` function of the [anytime](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=anytime) package:

```
 > anytime::anydate(c("2007.10", "2007.11", "2007.12"))
 [1] "2007-10-01" "2007-11-01" "2007-12-01" 
 >
```

You will have to turn your *numeric* input into character first:

```
 > anytime::anydate(as.character(c(2007.10, 2007.11, 2007.12)))  
 [1] "2007-10-01" "2007-11-01" "2007-12-01" 
 >
```

The `anydate()` function *can* convert from numeric but it assumes a *numeric* representation (*i.e.*

```
> as.numeric(Sys.Date())   
[1] 19294                  
>
```

Generally speaking your input is of course incomplete as a *date* needs a day besides a month and a year.

Comment: THank you! But when i read in csv, 2007.1 turns into 2007.10. do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: If you meant 2007.01 you might have to write it that way.  2007.1 and 2007.10 are numerically identical after all (just printed differently).

Comment: Oh i just used as.character(date) it works for me now. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

The root of the issue is the `date` column is being read in as numeric, and `2007.1` becomes `2007.10` because some values have two places after the decimal. There is no way to distinguish these values from “true Octobers” — e.g., `2007.10` in the original data file — once the data have been read in. Instead, you have to read them in as character from the get-go. This example does so using the `col_types` argument to `readr::read_csv()`. I then converts to date using [`lubridate::ym()`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/ymd.html), since the values are in **y**ear-**m**onth format.

```
library(readr)
library(lubridate)

# stand in for raw data file

df_raw <- "date,val
2007.1,1
2007.11,2
2007.12,3
2008.01,4
2008.02,5
2008.10,6
"

df1 <- read_csv(
  df_raw,
  col_types = cols(date = col_character())
)

ym(df1$date)
# [1] "2007-01-01" "2007-11-01" "2007-12-01" "2008-01-01" "2008-02-01"
# [6] "2008-10-01"
```

You can do the same with the `colClasses` argument to `utils::read.csv()`:

```
df1 <- read.csv(
  "filename.csv", 
  colClasses = c(date = "character")
)
```

Comment: Thank you! this is my read csv. df <- read.csv("PS_09_orangutans.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",") Do you know what to add in this code so when it reads in, it automatically won't change 2007.1 to 2007.10?

Comment: `colClasses = "character"`

Comment: You would add `colClasses = c(date = "character")`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_raw <- structure(list(date = c("2007.1", "2007.10")), 
                    row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
df_raw
#     date
#1  2007.1
#2 2007.10
write.csv(df_raw, "df_raw.csv")

read.csv("df_raw.csv") # uh oh
#  X   date
#1 1 2007.1
#2 2 2007.1

read.csv("df_raw.csv", colClasses = "character") # better
#  X    date
#1 1  2007.1
#2 2 2007.10


# with conversion suggested by @zephryl
df_loaded <- read.csv("df_raw.csv", colClasses = "character") 
df_loaded$date = lubridate::ym(df_loaded$date)
df_loaded
#  X       date
#1 1 2007-01-01
#2 2 2007-10-01
```